# tfs 2017 clone an "old" xaml build definition

Tags: build-definition

We are currently updating from TFS 2010 to TFS 2017. In 2010 we had the power tools to allow us to clone build definitions. In 2017 it is possible to clone the new build definitions via context menu. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/62e45991-842b-48bc-923c-9eafb2dff021/clone-build-definition?forum=TFService

Is there still a way to clone the "old" xaml build definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We strongly suggest you migrate from XAML builds to new builds as XAML build is deprecated in TFS 2017. Please refer to the following link to migrate XAML builds:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds

If you still want to use XAML builds, we suggest you to configure the XAML build server on a separate machine, then point the build controller to the collection in TFS2017. According to document [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements#tfs-build-compatibility), TFS 2017 works with:

- TFS 2015 Xaml Controller
- TFS 2013 Xaml Controller
- TFS 2010 Xaml Controller

You still can use the feature in PowerTools to clone XAML build definitions, as PowerTools is a addin of VS. You need to match the version of the TFS Power Tools with your Visual Studio client:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power